# Why am I getting Module Error when importing Zipline?

Tags: python, pandas, package, zipline

So I am trying to install zipline and zipline live. I have installed all of the main packages needed for this, and when I do `pip install zipline` I get no errors. But then when I go into python and do import zipline I get the error:

```
    >>> import zipline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\zipline\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import data
  File "C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import loader
  File "C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\loader.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
  File "C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (
  File "C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import deprecate_kwarg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.util._decorators'
```

I have tired `pip install pandas.util._decorators` but this has not worked. I also tried changing to a more up-to-date pandas, but zipline and zipline live do not support this . Right now I have pandas 0.18.1

Comment: Please specify which packages and versions you're using.

Comment: Also, the installation instructions that I found warn that installing using pip may be slightly more complicated than for the typical library.

Comment: _I also tried changing to a more up-to-date pandas, but zipline and zipline live do not support this . Right now I have pandas 0.18.1_ I'm not sure if it's also the case on Windows, but I just checked on macOS, and the newest version of zipline through Conda requires Pandas 0.22.0.